# Htaccess 403 and HTTP_REFERER Wildcard

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, nginx, http-status-code-403

I am trying to deny direct access and cross domain access for my website, so i am trying to use wildcard access.

Only my website and the trusted domain can able to access my assets like image, java-script, css file etc.

> I am trying like this *.example.com so it will allow access to all
> https://www.example.com, http://www.example.com, http://example.com,
> https://example.com, https://subdomain.example.com etc

Code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^ .*\.example\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^ .*\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(txt|ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

My assets is still not blocking for direct access and cross domain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(txt|ico|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|js|css)$ - [F,NC,L]
```

Replace your `yoursite.com` with your main domain name in the condition above.

Comment: It blocking for `https://portal.example.com/` and my assest `https://www.example.com/assets/img/logo.png` . i want which enable for all subdomain `anything.example.com` in both `https` and `http`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep It blocks all subdomains `http` , `https` under `example.com` . Try using the same code in every htaccess you have for subdomains.

Comment: But i want to allow for all subdomain `anything.example.com` can able to use assets of `example.com`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep Sorry , that's a typo in my previous comment. I meant the rule blocks all refereeing domains except `example.com` and all its subdomains .

Comment: I am confused, then why it blocking assets from `example.com` in `portal.example.com`

Comment: @shanmugapradeep It might be that your `portal.example.com` is pointing to a different document root and using a different htaccess to serve the URLs. If this is the case then you will need to paste this code in that htaccess too.

Comment: `root` is `example.com` folder and `root/portal` is `portal.example.com` folder and i see `portal.example.com` have it own `.htaccess`, i guess that what making it a problem. i guess i have to update in both `.htaccess` file